# after Ajax get content, I want call another ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I create ajax call in sidebar, when i click Color in navigation it works perfectly and everything fine here.

code is:

```
<a id='color'>Color</a>
```

Javascript function:

```
 document.getElementById('color').addEventListener('click', color);
function color(){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'setting/color.php', true);
xhr.onload = function(){
if(this.status == 200){
 history.pushState(null, null, '?c=color');
 document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = this.responseText;
} else if(this.status = 404){
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = 'Not Found';
}
}
xhr.onerror = function(){
console.log('Request Error...');
}
xhr.send();
}
```

after it, i want on Color page This code, It is on color.php, which is from ajax Call.

```
            <div class="f-col s1 m1 l1">
                <label class="container f-padding">
                  <input class="cols" type="radio" name="cols" value="dark light-hover">
                  <span class="checkmark dark"></span>
                </label>
            </div>


            <div class="f-col s1 m1 l1">
                <label class="container f-padding">
                  <input class="cols" type="radio" name="cols" value="light dark-hover" checked="checked">
                  <span class="checkmark light"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
```

Javascript function is here:

```
var colito = document.getElementsByClassName('cols');

var i;
for(i=0;i < colito.length;i++){
colito[i].addEventListener('click', colorSid);
function colorSid(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var cols = this.value;
  var params = "cols="+cols;

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '../phppath/color.php', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.onload = function(){
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
  xhr.send(params);
}
}
```

It dont work if I dont refresh page, what is problem anyone know?

Comment: Have you hear about Promise ? That could help you having a pretty code. This would make something like `doFirstAction().then(doSometingElse).catch(e => {throw e});`

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thank you k0pemikus for link, i will make something for improve my english :)

Zyigh  Can you make example on my code? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! code is there inside first ajax function ^_^

```
 document.getElementById('color').addEventListener('click', color);
 function color(){
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('GET', 'setting/color.php', true);
 xhr.onload = function(){
 if(this.status == 200){
 history.pushState(null, null, '?c=color');
 document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = this.responseText;
var colito = document.getElementsByClassName('cols');

var i;
 for(i=0;i < colito.length;i++){
colito[i].addEventListener('click', colorSid);
 function colorSid(e){
e.preventDefault();
var cols = this.value;
var params = "cols="+cols;

 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('POST', '../phppath/color.php', true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
 xhr.onload = function(){
   console.log(this.responseText);
 }
 xhr.send(params);
 }
 }
 } else if(this.status = 404){
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = 'Not Found';
}
  }
 xhr.onerror = function(){
 console.log('Request Error...');
  }
 xhr.send();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep your html in a string in `color.php` and echo it.

```
$html = '<div class="f-col s1 m1 l1">
            <label class="container f-padding">
              <input class="cols" type="radio" name="cols" value="dark light-hover">
              <span class="checkmark dark"></span>
            </label>
        </div>


        <div class="f-col s1 m1 l1">
            <label class="container f-padding">
              <input class="cols" type="radio" name="cols" value="light dark-hover" checked="checked">
              <span class="checkmark light"></span>
            </label>
        </div>';

echo $html;
```

Comment: first try to debug whether your request and response are working properly. I mean just keep `echo test` in `color.php`. Then console response and check whether you are getting the response.If you don't get a response the issue is your javascript. Why don't you try out jquery in this case?

Comment: In your javascript check for 500 response which is **Server Internal Error**

Comment: When i open color.php from ajax, it work, after when i click class='cols' it dont work, if i refresh page and again click class='cols' it work...

Answer (score 0):

I see your javascript code.you put function which is called in event listner, It must be outside of your javascript for loop.and below i write code for answer of question you mentioned in title.

```
$.ajax({
     url:"your url",
     type: "GET",
     beforeSend: function(xhr){
         //xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
     },
     success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var resp = JSON.parse(data);

          //call another ajax function here

      }
  });
```

Comment: I dont want it in jquery, i want it in Pure javascript